# Appropriate map projection for the Pacific Ocean

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography

I've found this map that shows the Pacific Ocean from http://www.transpacificproject.com:

[image: Pacific Ocean by the Transpacific Project]

I'd like to produce a similar map, for the same region of the earth and I'd like to use the same projection as I think it illustrates well the distance between the continents.

I've searched for the name of this projection, but I don't think I know the answer yet. At first I thought it was Robison but according to Wikipedia:

> The Robinson projection is a map projection of a world map **which shows the entire world at once**.

Which doesn't seem to be the case. (Can't see Europe and Africa here.)

So, my question is two-fold: what is the name of this projection? Should I use it to illustrate what I said earlier or should I use something else?

Comment: Do you know what you mean by "distance between the continents"? If the map is a Homolographic Equal Area -- as suggested by blindJesse below -- then it is not necessarily good at representing distances. Areas, yes, perfectly.

Comment: A good place for this question would also be CartoTalk.com.  There are some very projection-knowledgeable folks on that forum.

Comment: @martinf actually, I just meant that I didn't think it had too much distortion, but wasn't sure. I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears to be a truncated Mollweide projection, centred on 160°W.

Googling the image gives http://odtmaps.com/detail.asp?product_id=WE-Pac-Rim-32x47rolled, which lists the projection as "Homolographic Equal Area", another name for Mollweide. Generating a Mollweide at 160W using http://kartograph.org/showcase/projections/#mollweide and overlaying gives an excellent fit:

[image: overlay of candidate maps]

As you can see, the map is truncated at approx. 60S, 70N, 55W and 95E. In addition, a blue border has been added, which could cause some confusion in the area of Brazil and the Alaskan/Canadian Arctic.

Mollweide is an excellent projection for full-Earth maps as it is equal-area and represents high latitudes accurately (not stretching the poles into lines), but given that it distorts significantly towards the edges and does not preserve distances, a distance-preserving projection such as [two-point equidistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-point_equidistant_projection) might be better if you want to show the distances between the continents bordering the Pacific.

Comment: Antarctica is not a Pacific continent. Everything south of 60 degrees south is the Southern Ocean, not the Pacific Ocean. It may be an arbitrary dividing line, but it is nevertheless a dividing line.

Comment: @MikeScott ah, good point - I suppose that's why the map is truncated unequally north-south.

Comment: All answers are fantastic. I'll select yours because it answers the question most thoroughly and provides great illustration!

Comment: Agreed, the blue border is ridiculously confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Although it is not exactly what you are asking for, you could have a look at ***World Vertical Perspective***, which will not show the entire world, like a Robinson would, for instance.

You have not specified what software you are using, but I once made the following map in ArcGIS:

[image]

You would have to go into the projection parameters and change the standard meridian to make the globe spin to the area you want to show (i.e. specify a longitude value in the middle of the Pacific Ocean).

**EDIT, March 18**:
Took me a few days to remember the name, but there is  really cool software to work with projections. It is called [Geocart](http://www.mapthematics.com/). It is proprietary, but maybe you have access to it, or you can at least get the demo. This software supports a very large range of projections, including some obscure ones, and the projections themselves are grouped by their type, which is smart:

[image]

I do not know too many people who use it, but it is neat for projection geeks or for those who want to learn more about projections. Might also be a good starting point to find some of the more unusual ones, such as the Batman projection (OK, this one is officially called [Hammer retroazimuthal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_retroazimuthal_projection), but look it up and you will get what I am talking about ;-) )...

Answer (score 6):

Not as stylish, but you could use:

PCD Mercator : http://epsg.io/3832

EPSG: 3832

Like produced in QGIS:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In general any map centered on the Pacific is going to show how big it is. The Pacific is objectively large - 30% of Earth's surface.

Your map looks like it might be a cut-off Mollweide projection (notice that it not only cuts off Europe and Africa, but also doesn't show the poles or even the northern edges of the northern continents) - the cut-off latitudes cause the flat top and bottom edges (the poles on this projection are round), and the cut-off longitudes create the shallower curves, both of which are conventionally associated with the Robinson. The outline of a full Mollweide world map is a 2:1 ellipse.

I can't find a good example map centered on the Pacific, but here's the shape of a Mollweide map showing <s>120 degrees of latitude</s> (centered on the Equator) and 180 degrees of longitude, compared with the whole world (EDIT: I misunderstood the projection - I am not sure exactly how much latitude my example image represents)

[image: Map shape image]

The image quality makes the map you posted very hard to read, so I haven't tried to determine what the exact cutoff latitudes and longitudes are.

Answer (score 4):

It appears they borrowed the map from [here](http://odtmaps.com/detail.asp?product_id=WE-Pac-Rim-32x47rolled). The projection is listed there as "Homolographic Equal Area".