# How to have map project East Asia connecting to Atlanta?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

Is there a projected coordinate system that enables the eastern part of Asia to connect with Alaska?

my current setup is this:I wish for the entirety of east Asia and part of Alaska to be on the same side. So the end of the left-hand side to connect to the right-hand side in one map.

[image]

Comment: Your title and question body ask about different US placenames. This is likely a duplicate  with questions about shifting the globe to 0-360 longitude.

Comment: maybe one of those maps could suit you, but there are many more and you can change the central meridian in the properties of many projection. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138735/appropriate-map-projection-for-the-pacific-ocean if you stay at high latitude, polar azimuthal are also nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to properties of the map > projected coordinates > World > WGS 1984 PDC Mercator.

Gives what you were looking for:

[image]