# PostgreSQL - Geography shape becomes invalid

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a geography that looks like this in geojson.io:
[image]

I have a geography column in DB, which stores the above geography that looks like this in pgAdmin:
[image]

As you can see in the pgAdmin image, it has created invalid geography by connecting the lines in between.

Is there any way to fix this issue or I will need to recreate the geography to somehow it do not create such an invalid geography shape?

Comment: That's a pgadmin display problem not an actual geography problem

Comment: NO. When I try to match any UK region. It gets matched due to the lines cross in between

Comment: How are you doing the "match"? A simple envelope test?

Comment: By using ST_Contains and ST_Intersects

Answer (score 1):

This is a projection problem, your data is probably fine. Your polygons are cut by the limits of the projection you are using to visualize. It seems to be 3857 (web mercator, the default of many tools), so the limit is the 180° longitude, the line somewhere around the changing date, a little bit in russia down until new zealand:

[image: Web mercator projection]

When drawing, each line will be drawn between two consecutives points using the shortest path available, but in projection 3857 the path between alaska and below russia is across the world, it cannot teleport from one side of the map to the other (just imagine you have a rectangular paper map, don't be fooled by the fact the map is repeated right and left in the web visualization).

If you want to correctly display this polygon, you need to either split the polygon using the line at longitude 180° and latitude -90° to 90°, or change the projection you use to visualize your data. Try display your geom usin QGis with the projection
102016 for example (which is polar), or try to find a projection that is centered along the 180° longitude instead of the 0° longitude if all your data is around the pacific ocean (some idea here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/138779/120505).